# rails foreign key violation error key not present in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

I have two models division definition and model definition

division definition :

```
    has_many :model_definitions, inverse_of: :division_definition, foreign_key: :division_definition_id, primary_key: :division_definition_id
```

ModelDefinition:

```
   belongs_to :division_definition, inverse_of: :model_definitions, foreign_key: :division_id,  primary_key: :division_id
```

In Db structure

```
   def change
    create_table :model_definitions do |t|
      t.string :model_id , null: false, unique: true
      t.string :car_model_name , null: false
      t.belongs_to :division_definition , null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :model_definitions, :division_definition_id
    add_foreign_key :model_definitions, :division_definitions,      on_delete: :restrict
   end
```

divisiondefinition table

```
    def change
      create_table :division_definitions do |t|
        t.integer :division_definition_id, null: false
        t.string :division_name,null: false

        t.timestamps null: false
      end
      add_index :division_definitions, :division_definition_id,   unique: true
    end
```

When i try to create model definition through division definition in console i'm getting following error

```
   PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "model_definitions" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_addc8b742e"
   DETAIL:  Key (division_definition_id)=(124) is not present in table "division_definitions".
   : INSERT INTO "model_definitions" ("model_id", "car_model_name", "division_definition_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "model_definitions" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_addc8b742e"
   DETAIL:  Key (division_definition_id)=(124) is not present in table "division_definitions".
   : INSERT INTO "model_definitions" ("model_id", "car_model_name", "division_definition_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
   from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared'
```

This is what i tried,

```
   DivisionDefinition.create(division_definition_id: '124', division_name: 'BMW')
   a = DivisionDefinition.last.model_definitions.build(model_id: 'bmw1', car_model_name: 'bmw1')
   a = DivisionDefinition.last.model_definitions.build(model_id: 'bmw1', car_model_name: 'bmw1')
   a.save
```

If i remove add_foreign_key from db i am able to create model definition through divisiondefinition

what is the error i'm making in migration file?

Comment: can you please post your division definition migration file too?

Comment: yea it seems to be a problem in your migration

Comment: @sonalkr132 : division definition table updated in the post

Comment: Remove null: false for `belongs_to` this should work. Try that.

Comment: Also why is this `t.integer :division_definition_id, null: false` used? Id is automatically created.

Comment: I need to user division_definition_id to be my primary and foreign key because this is going to be referred in model definition not the id

Answer (score 0):

Your ModelDefinitions class refers to `:division_id` which appears nowhere else in your code.